# Can a MACRO be compared in #if with non numeric value

Tags: c++, c, macros, comparison, conditional-statements

consider the following

```
#if TABLE_SIZE>200
#undef TABLE_SIZE
#define TABLE_SIZE 200
```

[The macro TABLE_SIZE is being compared](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

is it possible that its compared with a non numeric value like,

```
#if MACRO==ABCDEF123
```

I tried it but compiler complains of ABCDEF123 not being defined and assumes it as 0.

Comment: Reopened as this is also tagged C++ which could attract constructive template-based solutions.

Comment: @Bathsheba, actually I upvoted your comment for reopening this Q. But I realized that macros & templates don't get along in this context. I am not sure about the history of this Q. Was the linked Q only marked as duplicate earlier? Nevertheless, I don't see that anything beyond the answers given in that post is possible. Also it seems that, the code in this Q as it is (with `#endif`) actually compiles fine. Mostly OP meant whatever is asked in the linked Q.

Answer (score 0):

For true portability, the *expression* in `#IF expression` can only contain integer and character constants. The C and C++ preprocessors can also evaluate `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `<<`, `>>`, `!=`, `==` and the two logical operators `&&` and `||` which obey the short-circuiting rules of standard C and C++.

So no, you can't compare a string directly.